# XAMPP couldn't open default browser in xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, apache2, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP on my Xubuntu 18.04, installed fine but while clicking on "Go to Application" on the XAMPP menu it shows an alert box saying "Failed to execute default web browser input/output error". So, please help me. I don't know how to solve this problem, tried a few things like checking the preferred applications.

Please help ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

All go to application is doing is trying to open a Web browser to a specific address. If you're running default xampp the address should just be http://localhost/

Comment: yea, the localhost works but it's little bit unsatisfying, that it doesn't open the browser from the application itself.

Comment: One thing I want to ask which Ubuntu flavour you use? and why?