# Failed to execute default Web browser (input/output error) on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I have this type of error when installing XAMPP and I just skip it and continue the installation. But every time I select "Go to Application" it gives me the same error [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgTCj.png) `Failed to execute defaut Web Browser input/output error`.
I also reinstall XAMPP every time I recieved this error.

Although, I can run XAMPP by typing the localhost in browser but it doesn't gives me the privilege to install wordpress in `/opt/lampp/temp/`. WordPress installation says `the folder is not empty`.

So I just tried to fix first the `Failed to execute defaut Web Browser input/output error`. And I've tried to change browsers and run `sudo ./manager-linux-64.run` but different browser have different type of error.

- For Vivaldi it says: `[14077:14077:0606/210914.153103:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/6381`
- For Firefox: `Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/ginoongflores/.Xauthority which is owned by ginoongflores`

I noticed, this an old problem in the internet but I think there is no concrete solution for this one. I find the similar problem in these links:

- https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=259873&sid=5f5130c6cab6651899e2db707666ad43
- [XAMPP couldn't open default browser in xubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075986/xampp-couldnt-open-default-browser-in-xubuntu-18-04)

But no right solution as of the moment. And I've spent 2 days to figure this out. So, I'm trying my luck for this one, If anyone could have the right solution or maybe its time to ditch XAMPP in my ubuntu-based machine.